# Need to change the width of the drop-down menu, depending on the number of nested ul

Tags: javascript, menu

Need to change the width of the drop-down menu, depending on the number of nested ul.

```
if( $('.mg-main-menu li .submenu li ul').size() == 1 )
{
    $('.mg-main-menu li .submenu').css({"width" : "250px"}); 
};


if( $('.mg-main-menu li .submenu li ul').size() == 2 )
{
    $('.mg-main-menu li .submenu').css({"width" : "500px"}); 
};


if( $('.mg-main-menu li .submenu li ul').size() == 3 )
{
    $('.mg-main-menu li .submenu').css({"width" : "750px"}); 
};


if( $('.mg-main-menu li .submenu li ul').size() == 4 )
{
    $('.mg-main-menu li .submenu').css({"width" : 1000px"}); 
};
```

**Structure**

```
<ul class="mg-main-menu">
    <li><a href="#"></a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#"></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>   

    <li><a href="#"></a>    
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#"></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>   

    <li><a href="#"></a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#"></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#"></a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#"></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Code does not work :)

How to write working code with the property $(this)
Width should be applied precisely to the desired category, and not all.

I can not understand how to do, please help.

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to do, provide sufficient context, and possibly create a jsfiddle/codepen reproduction of the problem.

Comment: I want that in the presence of 1,2,3,4 ul drop-down menu changed its size. It seems everything is clear ...

Comment: You haven't provided your HTML and/or a clear description of _what_ doesn't work. On a sidenote, you should use `.length` instead of `.size()` ([see documentation](http://api.jquery.com/size/)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
$('.mg-main-menu li .submenu').each(function () {
    $(this).css({
        width: (250 * Math.min($('li ul', this).length, 4)) + 'px'
    });
});
```

(remove the `Math.max()` call if you don't want to limit the width).